# How to get out of grub rescue and install windows?

Tags: grub2, windows, live-usb, grubrescue

So I tried uninstalling ubuntu. I made a live USB just in case and also loaded a version of windows onto another USB. I deleted all the associated linux partitions and was hoping on installing windows now, but right now im getting a grub rescue screen that I can't get rid of. How can I delete it and install windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you are totally getting rid of Ubuntu from your system, the grub rescue screen does not matter. If you are using a bootable USB and you still get to grub rescue it means you are not booting from your USB at all. 
First of all you need to find out why you are not able to boot from your USB and fix that.
After this you should boot from the Ubuntu live CD and format the hard disk to something windows can read (NTFS).
Finally boot the computer to a Windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete anything.  Just boot to your Windows installation disk and install Windows.  Windows installer will overwrite the grub you have remaining on your computer.

Grub is a Boot Manager that is associated with Ubuntu.  You've deleted the Ubuntu files, now Grub isn't working.

**Summary**

Use a Linux installer to Linux.  Use a Windows installer to install Windows.